# Set entity framework DDL generation language

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, table-per-type

I am using Entity Framework with Visual Studio 2012 or 2010. I am working together with colleagues who have a different language version (German) of Visual Studio installed.

Some of our models use inheritance. When generating the database from the model (using standard values: TablePerTypeStrategy.xaml and SSDLToSQL10.tt) EF generates inheritance constraints. The names of these constraints are localized (x_inherits_y vs x_erbt_y). This means, every time someone makes a change to the model and generates the SQL file all the constraint names are updated with the localized version.

This is starting to become a major annoyance as we need to know the names of the constraints. Sometimes we need to update already deployed databases and there is no way to know whether they have been created with the German or English constraint names. This makes writing update scripts impossible without access to the database.

Is there some way to prevent Visual Studio from localizing these names other than force all developers to use the same Language version?

Comment: Is moving to code first an option for you guys?

Comment: We might explore it for new projects, but the project I am currently using this for has been running for more than 3 years now. While this situation is annoying, I do not think it warrants migrating the project to code-first.

Comment: Besides, wouldn't code-first have a similar problem? I haven't used it yet, but as far as I can see it also automagically maps classes to database tables and I assume it creates constraints on those tables. Will those constraint names not also be localized?

Comment: Code-first by default uses names of properties to compose FK names.

Comment: Actually, having a second look at it: Model first also uses property names to compose FK names. The issue lies with the inheritance constraints. How are those names created in code first? I'm afraid they will have the same problem.